# Relation between convergence in $L^{p}$ and $L^{q}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, sequence-of-function

I would like to find a sequence $(u_{n})$, where $u_{n} \in L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^{N})$ for all $p\geq 2$ and such that $u_{n}(x) \rightarrow 0$ a.e in $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ and $|u_{n}|_{L^{2}} \rightarrow +\infty$, but $|u_{n}|_{p} \leq C$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and for all $p>2$.

In general, can we derive some property of $(u_{n})$ in $L^{2}$ through the properties of $(u_{n})$ in $L^{p}$ for $p> 2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following function verifies your assumptions
$$
u_n(x) =\frac{1}{(\ln(n+1))^{1/4}} \frac{\mathbf 1_{|x|<n}}{(1+|x|)^{N/2}}.
$$
Indeed, the fact that $\|u_n\|_{L^p} < C$ and $u_n\to 0$ a.e. are not difficult to see (even more, $u_n\to 0$ in $L^p$ for $p>2$ actually).

Moreover,
$$
\|u_n\|_{L^2}^2 = \frac{C_N}{(\ln(n+1))^{1/2}} \int_0^n \frac{r^{N-1}}{(1+r)^{N}}\,\mathrm d r \underset{n\to\infty}∼ C_N\ln(n)^{1/2}
$$

In general indeed, it is not possible to get properties of $u_n$ in $L^2$ from properties in $L^p$, except for instance on bounded domains.

Comment: Please, is this a standard example? If not, could you tell a bit about your intuition/thought process to come up with it?

Comment: The way to come up with the example is to remark that $L^p_{\mathrm{loc}} \subset L^2_{\mathrm{loc}}$ if $p>2$. So one can approximately think that only the decay for large values is stronger in $L^2$. Hence I took the function $1/(1+|x|)^{N/2}$, that is the function that is almost but not in $L^2$ because decaying too slowly, but in all the other $L^p$ with $p>2$. Now since I want $u_n$ to be in $L^2$ but to have infinite limit in $L^2$, I just take truncations $|x|<n$ of the above function.

Comment: Now I have functions that are bounded in $L^p$ and converge to $\infty$ in $L^2$, but we want functions that converge to $0$ in $L^p$. We just have to multiply by a factor that goes to $0$ sufficiently slowly such that it does not break the convergence to $\infty$ in $L^2$, so for instance $1/\ln(n+1)^{1/4}$.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it was most instructive